# How to break a list based on list item and create relevant strings

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list similar to the following one:

```
['2019','Melbourne','region1','suburb1','\n', '2018','region1','Melbourne','\n']
```

I want to break(split) and store the information of the list based on '\n'. It means I want to create following strings from the above list:

```
string1='2019, Melbourne, region1, suburb1'
string2='2018, region1, Melbourne'
```

I know how to do that using a simple for loop and playing around indices but I wonder if someone could assist me with doing the mentioned task in a more professional way. Because playing around the indices makes my code a bit complex and unreadable.

Comment: convert it into string then split it accordingly.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar That's like taking a nearly complete puzzle, mixing it up, and starting all over again.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of the desired strings, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with an appropriate key function to chunk the list and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to turn the chunks into strings:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['2019','Melbourne','region1','suburb1','\n', '2018','region1','Melbourne','\n']

[', '.join(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=lambda s: s != '\n') if k]
# ['2019, Melbourne, region1, suburb1', '2018, region1, Melbourne']
```

Note that `groupby` returns a lazy iterator producing equally lazy groups. So this does not build any unnecessary intermediate in-memory lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this! using `re`

```
import re
l = ['2019','Melbourne','region1','suburb1','\n', '2018','region1','Melbourne','\n']
res = re.split("[\r\n]+",' '.join(l))[:-1]
string1 = res[0].strip().replace(' ',', ')
string2 = res[1].strip().replace(' ',', ')

# string1 --> '2019, Melbourne, region1, suburb1'
# string2 --> '2018, region1, Melbourne'
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to concatenate the given list into a string using join() and then use split on the string to split in to list. Following is the code:

```
test=['2019','Melbourne','region1','suburb1','\n', '2018','region1','Melbourne','\n']
test_string=",".join(test)

sep_list= test_string.split("\n")
```

You will get a list of strings separated by "\n"

Comment: `','` is not the connector wanted by the OP (that is `', '`). Also, you will have to remove (strip) spurious `','` from the tokens returned by your `split`.

Comment: You're right. I just ran the code and noticed the extra ','. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()`,but i get an unexpected result so i use regex

```
import re
l = ['2019','Melbourne','region1','suburb1','\n', '2018','region1','Melbourne','\n']
string1 , string2 = re.findall("(?!,)([^\n]+)(?=,)" ,",".join(l))
print(string1,string2)
```

1. (?!,) : use to match string began without `,` -> match but not contain in result
2. ([^\n]+) : match str until `\n`
3. (?=,) : match str which end with `,` -> match but not contain in result

Answer (score 0):

I propose solution like this:

```
listin=['2019','Melbourne','region1','suburb1','\n', '2018','region1','Melbourne','\n'];
listsout=[];sublist=[];
for val in listin:
    if val.__contains__('\n')==False:
        sublist.append(val);
    else:
        listsout.append([i for i in sublist]);
        sublist = [];
# --------------------------------------------
strings = [', '.join(sublist) for sublist in listsout];
```

Comment: "I know how to do that using simple for loop and playing around indices but I [want] a more professional way."